# Hyperref link spanning two lines

Tags: hyperref, dvi

in my tex source file I have a link like that:

```
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warm_dark_matter}{Warm 
Dark Matter}
```

This link starts on one line and ends on the next line. The problem is that when I compile it like `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`, I see "Warm Dark Matter" colored, but can't click on it to open the link.

When file is compiled with `pdflatex` everything is fine, so what can be the problem in the first method?

I can't move link in one line because I have automatic tex-processing system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dvips can't break links. See section 7  "Limitations
Wrapped/broken link support" in readme.pdf of hyperref and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-breaklinks.

Comment: I'm sorry but that means I should use another driver?

Comment: Yes, you already experienced that pdflatex can break links.

Comment: Ok, but then I also need to convert all eps images :)

Comment: Following Ulrike'S link you can read: "Other drivers (notably those for PDFTeX and for dvipdfm) don’t suffer from this problem". So using dvipdfm(x) might be easier!

Comment: @dragoon I think breakurl package option can help you.