# hyperref package, breaklinks option

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, links

When I compile with LaTeX + dvips, I get the following warning message:

```
Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.  
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.  
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.
```

Right now, I am using the `report` document class and call the `hyperref` package with the following commands (I am using MikTeX 2.9 and WinEdt 7.0 on Windows 7)

```
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

The document compiles (using LaTeX+dvips) and the links spanning two lines appear to break correctly, but I receive the warning message. Is this a problem? How can I fix it? I tried to add the following package and compile using pdflatex (instead of LaTeX + dvips)

```
 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
```

but it produced the following warning message:

```
 >>> Loading package auto-pst-pdf <<<  

 Package pstricks Warning: ************************************ 
 (pstricks)                Option pdf needs a "pdflatex -shell-escape <file>" 
 (pstricks)                or a "pdflatex -enable-write18 <file>" 
 (pstricks)                (if you are using MikTeX) 
 (pstricks)                ************************************.
```

I also get the following error, which prevented me from being able to compile with pdflatex:

```
 Package ifplatform Warning: 
     shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows  

 ! Package auto-pst-pdf Error:
     "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
     auto-pst-pdf will not work!
```

Alternatively, I tried using the `epstopdf` package (and compiled with pdflatex), but that package is not compatible with the `psfrag` package. I am looking for a way to fix the breaklinks warning message (see above), without losing the ability to use eps figures and the `psfrag` package.

Comment: You need to compile using `pdflatex`, otherwise this won't work (see [Hyperref link spanning two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10725/5764) and [Link text doesn’t break at end line](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=breaklinks)). Is there a reason (or requirement) for using `dvips`?

Comment: I use eps figures.

Comment: use `pdflatex`, and [eps-figures-with-pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/eps-figures-with-pdflatex)

Comment: You're using conflicting declarations: if you use `latex+dvips` you mustn't load `pstricks` with the `pdf` option. Load the package `breakurl` after `hyperref` for being able to break URLs. However, switching to `pdflatex` by converting EPS files to PDF (which can be done automatically with the `epstopdf` package and the option `--shell-escape` to `pdflatex`) is better.

Comment: My understanding is that epstopdf can not handle psfrag

Comment: When I use epstopdf, the document compiles but it does not execute the psfrag commands.

Comment: Maybe you could use [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) instead of `epstopdf`. It handles `\psfrag` quite well...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you load the [`breakurl`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/breakurl/breakurl.pdf) package you can safely ignore the warning message issued by the `hyperref` package. It’s the dedicated purpose of the `breakurl` package to enable breakable URL links in case of the traditional DVI→PS→PDF document generation path supported by the `hdvips` output driver. If you want to get rid of the redundant `hyperref` warning message omit the `breaklinks` option, i.e.,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

or use the `silence` package:

```
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{hyperref}{You have enabled option `breaklinks'.}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

If you choose to switch from the DVI mode to the PDF mode of pdfTeX there will be no `hyperref` warning message and you won’t need the `breakurl` package since the `hpdftex` output driver is capable of breaking URL links itself. In this case, however, you additionally have to load a support package such as the [`pstool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/pstool.pdf) package facilitating the usage of `psfrag` features in the PDF mode of pdfTeX. Moreover, you probably have to enable the `\write18{...}` construct, e.g. by passing the appropriate command-line option (`-shell-escape` in TeX Live/Linux) to the `pdflatex` program. A little example (You need an EPS file `pi.eps` containing the tag `pi`):

```
%% LaTeX master file test.tex: Process with pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstool}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  %% Include pi.eps and replace the tag ‘pi’ with π.
  \pstool{pi}{\psfrag{pi}{\(\pi\)}}
\end{figure}

\noindent
\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post a working example of the packages/options that are needed for pdf mode with the `psfrag` package?

Comment: Can you also explain why the warning message is issued and how the `breakurl` fixes the problem? This would be helpful for others who run into the same problem.

Comment: @richtera: I’ve upgraded my answer.

Comment: I tried using the silence package and the warning filter you suggested, but it did not work.

Comment: @richtera: With the TeX Live 2009 and current versions of the `hyperref` and `silence` packages, it works at least.

Comment: I am still hoping that someone can shed more light on this issue, since the silence package does not seem to work with LaTeX+dvips.

Comment: @richtera: In TeX Live 2012/Debian, it works. By the way, the output driver/mode is irrelevant for the `silence` package.